# How can I pull rows from multiple other worksheets into a master sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I want a Master Sheet to pull all rows from other worksheets based on the value in column U of those other worksheets.

I have a workbook for multiple users to input data into rows on multiple worksheets.
Not every row has values. I created column U to put a value of '1' if there is data in the row and a value of '0' if there is none.
However there are some rows that are blank throughout and those rows have no information.

```vb
Sub Button2_Click()

Dim a As Long
Dim b As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim c As Long
Dim d As Long

b = Worksheets.Count
a = Worksheets(i).Cells(Rows.Count, 21).Endt(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To b
    If Worksheets(i).Name = "MasterSheet" Then
        'do nothing
    Else
        For c = 1 To a
            If Worksheets(i).Cells(c, 15).Value = "1" Then

                Worksheets(i).Rows(c).Copy

                Worksheets("MasterSheet").Activate

                d = Worksheets("MasterSheet").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

                Worksheets("MasterSheet").Cells(d + 1, 1).Select

                ActiveSheet.Paste
            End If

        Next

        Application.CutCopyMode = False

        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MasterSheet").Cells(1, 1).Select

End Sub
```

This code does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this code.  I used the basic outline of what you sent and corrected a few things.  I also changed the variable names to make it clearer what each of the are for.

In your explanation you mentioned you would check column U (21) but in the code you were checking column 21 to find the last row but column O (15) for the number one.  I this code I'm checking all in column 21

I also added the Application.ScreenUpdating=False at the beginning which will make the code run much faster if you are copying many rows.
Finaly, the copy function allows for paste argument this allows you to directly paste what you copy to the destination you want without having to activate and select the sheet and range of your destination. This will make your code run much faster if you are doing this for many rows and sheets

```
Sub CopyRowsToMater()
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim TotalSheets As Long
Dim curSheet As Long
Dim curRow As Long
Dim LastRowMaster As Long
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    LastRowMaster = Worksheets("MasterSheet").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    TotalSheets = Worksheets.Count
    For curSheet = 1 To TotalSheets
        LastRow = Worksheets(curSheet).Cells(Rows.Count, 21).End(xlUp).Row
        
        If Worksheets(curSheet).Name = "MasterSheet" Then
        'do nothing
        Else
            For curRow = 2 To LastRow
                            
                If Worksheets(curSheet).Cells(curRow, 21).Value = "1" Then
                    Worksheets(curSheet).Rows(curRow).Copy Worksheets("MasterSheet").Cells(LastRowMaster + 1, 1)
                    LastRowMaster = LastRowMaster + 1
                End If
            Next
            
        End If
    Next
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("MasterSheet").Cells(1, 1).Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

ok first remember that when you do a program it always have order and it is by line so you will have error if put this

```
b = Worksheets.Count
a = Worksheets(i).Cells(Rows.Count, 21).Endt(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To b
```

because you want "a" take a value from sheet number "i" but in that moment "i" dont have any value

Second you wrote worng  `Endt(xlUp).Row` is `End(xlUp).Row` you put a extra "t"

Third if you open two "For" you need to close with two "next" same problem with "if"